# Trying to get property of non-object using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have try to make my function but when id is empty the function return a empty array and got "Trying to get property of non-object" ... using laravel 5.2

```
  public static function NameFunction($id) {
    if(!empty($id)) {
        $Table = Table::find($id);
        if(count($Table) > 0)
        {
            return $Table;
        }
    } else {
        $return = array('name' => 'NULL');
        return $return;
    }
}
```

How I use the function

```
  {{ ClassName::NameFunction($idCat)->name }}
```

I know is not an object but how can I fix this ?

Comment: Because array has __no__ properties. And array is __not__ an object.

Comment: Yeap bro , But how can I fix it ?

Comment: Could you clarify your question. What are you trying to achieve? It looks like you are trying to use it in a templating engine. You either need to check if 'name' exists before you use it or return an object from your function that has a 'name' property

Comment: `$return = (object) array('name' => 'NULL');`

Comment: Cast the array to an object like @PaulSpiegel demonstrates.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's the idiomatic way to solve this in Laravel, but I suppose that if some item is not found something else should be done. So maybe you need to check something like:

```
public static function NameFunction($id) {
    if(!empty($id)) {
        $Table = Table::find($id);
        if(count($Table) > 0)
        {
            return $Table;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

$name = ClassName::NameFunction($idCat);
if ($name && !empty($name->name)) {
    echo $name->name;
} else {
    echo 'Not found'
}
```

Or maybe you can use `findOrFail` instead of `find` which will raise exception, which you can catch.

Answer (score 0):

I think this one should work

```
public static function NameFunction($id) {
    $default = array('name' => null);
    if(!empty($id)) {
        $Table = Table::find($id);
        if(count($Table) > 0)
        {
            return $Table;
        } 
        else 
        {
           return $default;
        }
    } else {
        return $default;
    }
}
```